# R: collect class information for variables in a data_frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to collect the `class` of some columns in my `data_frame`. So:

```
df_x = data_frame(date1 = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"), 
                              to = as.POSIXct("2016-01-03 12:00:00 UTC"), by = "hour", 
                              tz = "UTC"),
           date2 = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"), 
                              to = as.POSIXct("2016-01-03 12:00:00 UTC"), by = "hour", 
                              tz = "UTC"))

class(df_x$date1)
class(df_x$date2)
```

How can I collect up the results of a call to `class` for a bunch of columns? I can restrict to the first element of the return vector and then a call to `summarize_each` works:

```
# summarize_each
get_class = function(x) class(x)[1]
df_x %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(get_class), date1, date2)
```

I am wondering how I can get a number of variables cross max number of classes for any column `data_frame` for a bunch of variables in my `data_frame`? My guess is that some combination of a call to `do` and some post-processing would work here.

Desired result:

```
# desired result
df_result = data_frame(date1 = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                       date2 = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))

> df_result
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

    date1   date2
    (chr)   (chr)
1 POSIXct POSIXct
2  POSIXt  POSIXt
```

Comment: `sapply(df_x, class)`?

Comment: Or change to `get_class <- function(x) toString(class(x))` if you want them all.  What if there are 3 and 4 classes in some columns and only one in another?

Comment: @Frank Pretty much, except that I am going to push the result through a `tidyr:::matrixToDataFrame`.

Comment: Ok. You could maybe tag with tidyr as well, then. I know nothing about it.

Comment: @frank Not really, since the generic `as_data_frame` is [claimed to work on matrices](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/876), but not on my CRAN latest `dplyr_0.4.3`.

Comment: Maybe `do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df_x, class))`

Comment: is it possible to have mixed data in a column of a `data.frame`??

Comment: @JackeJR Not sure why that is relevant, but no, it is not.

Comment: @fg nu sorry I misunderstood. Would you not be better served by using a list since there can be unequal number of rows for each column?

Comment: @JackeJR Yes, that is part of the question -- I would like to create a `data_frame` with the maximum number of elements that `class` might return for my data, and in case there are less than that number for a particular column, then it should be filled in with `NULL`s. This is potentially sub-optimal, but it helps with the post-processing that I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use `dplyr` so sticking to just `base`:

## Create a data frame with different number of classes for each column.

```
df_x <- data.frame(date1 = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"),
                                      to = as.POSIXct("2016-01-03 12:00:00 UTC"), by = "hour",
                                      tz = "UTC"),
                   date2 = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 12:00:00 UTC"),
                                      to = as.POSIXct("2016-01-03 12:00:00 UTC"), by = "hour",
                                      tz = "UTC"),
                   character1 = sample(LETTERS, 49, replace = TRUE),
                   numeric1 = sample(1:100, 49, replace = TRUE))

df_x.class <- lapply(df_x, class)
```

## Create a function to make every vector in the list the same length

```
cbind.fill <- function(n) {
    vec.len <- max(unlist(lapply(n, length)))
    list.appended <- lapply(n, function(m) {
                            if(length(m) < vec.len) {
                                vec.append <- vec.len - length(m)
                                m <- c(m, rep(NA, vec.append))}
                            m})
    do.call(cbind, list.appended)}

cbind.fill(df_x.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will actually try the following one-liner with your example:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df_x, class))
```